# WKWebView WKWebsiteDataStore get cookies name and value as string

Tags: swift, xcode, cookies, wkwebview

Swift 5 iOS 13.0
Xcode 12.5.1

I called Wkwebview's Cookies through the code below.

```
let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    dataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies) in
        print(cookies)
    })
```

Now I get 'cookies' list like this:

```
[<NSHTTPCookie
version:1
name:_ga
value:GA1.2.1804988442.1625286371
expiresDate:'2021-07-10 04:26:11 +0000'
created:'2021-07-03 04:26:11 +0000'
sessionOnly:FALSE
domain:.mydomain.com
partition:none
sameSite:none
path:/
isSecure:FALSE
path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>,
<NSHTTPCookie
version:1
name:_gid
value:GA1.2.1499099201.1625286371
expiresDate:'2021-07-04 04:26:11 +0000'
created:'2021-07-03 04:26:11 +0000'
sessionOnly:FALSE
domain:.mydomain.com
partition:none
sameSite:none
path:/
isSecure:FALSE
path:"/" isSecure:FALSE>]
```

And I want to get each name and value as a string in the first and second cookie of the list.

Example)
Code

```
var dict: [String : String]
*Datas into the dictionary*
print(dict)
```

Result

```
["_ga":"GA1.2.1804988442.1625286371", "_gid":"GA1.2.1499099201.1625286371"]
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` function on your `cookies` array to transform the items in the array like this:

```
var dict: [String : String] = cookies.map { [$0.name: $0.value] }
```

Comment: @wookboy00 – if this answers your question please mark it as the accepted answer by tapping the checkmark.